# SQL Selecting and filtering by multiply values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Could you help me solve my problem?

I have table:

```
id     | party_id |  tag_id
_______|__________|__________
 1     |     5    |    1
 2     |     5    |    2
 3     |     5    |    3
 4     |     7    |    1
 5     |     7    |    6
 6     |     7    |    8
 7     |     7    |    9
 8     |     9    |    7
 9     |     9    |    6
```

I need to get a table in which the values ​​are the same `parties_id`'s that are strictly passed tags (like filtering):

example:

`tag_id = 1 and 3`

I should get:

`party_id = 5`

The problem is i couldn't use `WHERE IN` because is `OR` operator, but I need `AND`

What one query do you recommend for this `SELECT`?

Comment: I read this 3 times and cannot understand the question. Please rewrite/clarify.

Comment: @Ajk_P the same thing !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using `group by` with a `having` clause.  This is a so-called "set-within-sets" query.  Here is an example:

```
select party_id
from table t
group by party_id
having sum(tag_id = 1) > 0 and sum(tag_id = 3) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause counts the number of tags of a certain type for a given `party_id`.  The `> 0` ensures that at least one is present.

Comment: My gratitude is no limit. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the `IN` operator can't require a match of all of the things in the right side list, but you can `AND` multiple `IN` expressions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT party_id 
FROM testtable
WHERE 
  party_id IN (SELECT party_id FROM testtable WHERE tag_id = 1) 
  AND party_id IN (SELECT party_id FROM testtable WHERE tag_id = 3);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b4a15/1/0